# jeasyUI how to get attr ID in combogrid?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datagridviewcombobox, jquery-easyui

```
$('#mustGetID').combogrid({
    panelWidth:500,
    panelHeight:250,
    url: '<?= $url; ?>get_item.php',
    queryParams: {
      id_item: row.id_item
    },
    idField:'id_item',
    textField:'name_item',
    mode:'remote',
    fitColumns:true,
    nowrap: false,
    columns:[[
      {field:'id_item',title:'id_item',width:100},
      {field:'name_item',title:'name_item',width:200}
    ]]
    ,onSelect: function(index,row){
      alert($(this).attr('id');
    }
});
```

how i get attribute name of id **alert($(this).attr('id');** should be get **mustGetID** ,, anyone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` refers to the object that invoked it. That mean `this` will refer to the row on which you clicked. So in other words, you cannot get what you want easily. If the sole purpose is to get the id of combogrid element, what I would recommend is store the id of element in a variable and keep it in scope of onSelect so that you can access it. Something like,

```
var $el = 'mustGetID';

$('#' + $el).combogrid({
panelWidth:500,
panelHeight:250,
url: '<?= $url; ?>get_item.php',
queryParams: {
id_item: row.id_item
},
idField:'id_item',
textField:'name_item',
mode:'remote',
fitColumns:true,
nowrap: false,
columns:[[

     {field:'id_item',title:'id_item',width:100},
     {field:'name_item',title:'name_item',width:200}
]]
,onSelect: function(index,row){
alert($el);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$(row).attr('id)` as on select will return an index of that element and the element